# Create right to left legend in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, legend

Can I create right to left legend like this?
[image]

Comment: how do you display the joined Arabic characters ??

Comment: You should add `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8`  to environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but we are always happy to receive enhancements to the code base.